# Mysterious factor of "$5$" appearing in differential equation solution

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Please forgive my formatting, this is my first post here.

I am trying to solve the differential equation of the form:

$x' = A*x$

Where A is the $(n \times n)$ matrix:

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & -5 \\
        1 & -2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

I found the characteristic equation to be given by:

$\lambda^2 + 1 = 0$  which has roots $\lambda = {i, -i}$

Solving the augmented matrix $(A-i*I\ |\ 0)$ gave me the corresponding eigenvector $\phi_1$:

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 + i \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

This gives the complex solution $x = \phi_1*\exp(it)$

I know that if a solution can be written as $x = u(t) + i*v(t)$, then $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are also solutions.

By Euler's formula, I got:

$ u(t) = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 \cos (t) - \sin (t) \\
        \cos (t) \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

$ v(t) = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 \sin (t) + \cos (t) \\
        \sin (t) \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

However, the solution in textbook is:

$ u(t) = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        5 \cos (t) \\
        2 \cos (t) + \sin (t) \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

$ v(t) = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        5 \sin (t) \\
        - \cos (t) + 2 \sin (t) \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

What it looks like is they may have used a different eigenvalue / eigenvector, but I can't figure out what they used.

I believe my solutions are correct, I checked the first one $\big(u(t)\big)$ by plugging it back in to the original equation.

Wolfram alpha also gives the solution with the "$5$".  I wonder why?

Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas: I think I should wake up.

Comment: Go ahead and precede those universal functions like $\sin$ and $\ln$ with a backslash, as in `\sin`, so that they appear upright, like $a\sec x$ as opposed to $a sec x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you multiply your eigenvector by $2-i$, you get the alternative eigenvector
$$
\begin{pmatrix}5\\2-i\end{pmatrix}
$$
which leads to your textbook solution.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Can eigenvectors always be multiplied by a complex number to give another valid eigenvector?

Comment: @user6615434 Every nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector of the same eigenvalue. My teeth itch whenever I see “*the* eigenvector” since (with a few exceptions) they’re not unique.